# How to add auth or params in firebase.storage() request from react with restricted storage rules

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-hooks, firebase-storage

My Rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
      match /user/{userId}/{allPaths=**} {
    allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.resource.name == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

I want to restrict the access only for authenticated users with a particular userId.
and this is the function I am using to upload images. How to add auth or params in the request so that i can restrict access only for a particular user.

```
  const handleUpload = () => {
    /// storing a image

    const uploadTask = storage.ref(`images/${image.name}`).put(image);

    uploadTask.on(
      "state_changed",
      (snapshot) => {
        ////progress function..
        const progress = Math.round(
          (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
        );
        setProgress(progress);
      },
      (error) => {
        //Error function
        console.log(error);
        alert(error.message);
      },
      () => {
        ///upload complete function
        storage
          .ref("images")
          .child(image.name)
          .getDownloadURL()
          .then((url) => {
            //Use return URL
       
            setMyURL(url);
            setProgress(0);
            setCaption("");
            setImage(null);
          });
      }
    );
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a perfect fit for the `Custom Claims` and the Security Rules. Those allow you to add to each user a custom claim in the token so you can read it from securuty rules in both databases and storage rules.

You can find [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) more about them.

The hard part is that you can edit them only from a backend with the admin SDK. You could eather create a callable function where you control if a user can change that for another or (how I like to do it): I create a list or collection that has a firebase function trigger on creation and deletion. If someon's `userUid` is added to that list/collection a specific `custom claim` is added to that user uid. If he's `userUid` is delete from the list/collection the `custom claim` gets removed. With the `rules` for that list/collection you can control who can add and remove users from it.